# foreach loop for a complex dictionary is incorrect

Tags: .net, loops, powershell, dictionary

I'm using Windows 7 and PowerGUI Script Editor to write a ps1.
Here's a part of my codes:

```
#In global scope
$Type_Trans = "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[System.String,PSObject]"
$Type_Farms = "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[System.Int32,$Type_Trans]"

$Dic_Counts = New-Object $Type_Farms

#...puts some data in $Dic_Counts here...
#It is no problem with printing out it in console

#Now call the function below
Write-Data $Dic_Counts

Function Write-Data
{
    param(
        $Dic_Counts
    )

    Foreach($Dic_CountsSingle in $Dic_Counts)
    {
        Write-DataSingle $Dic_CountsSingle  #THIS LINE!
    }
}
```

It's very strange here: why is `Dic_CountsSingle` not a `KeyValuePair`, but is just the same as `Dic_Counts`??

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use

```
foreach ($Dic_CountsSingle in $DicCounts.GetEnumerator())
```

It's the same for hashtables in PowerShell, too, so not particularly surprising.

Comment: can you explain why this is?

Answer (score 8):

I do it like this:

```
$Dic_Counts.keys | %{ $Dic_Counts[$_]  }
```

Comment: Wow, what's this grammer? "%" ?

Comment: @bychance it is the alias for foreach-object

Answer (score 0):

I think it broke down here:

```
Foreach($Dic_CountsSingle in $Dic_Counts)
```

That foreach loop is expecting an array as it's second argument.  $Dic_Counts is a hash table, so it doesn't have an index. Now I'm wondering if an ordered hash table would work in a foreach loop. It does have an index.

Nope.  Foreach will not enumerate an ordered hash table, either.  Gotta do that yourself.

Comment: Well, I was wondering what exactly PowerShell will iterate on its own (either in `foreach` or in a pipeline). It does so for a `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`, which certainly isn't an array but there weren't any defining interfaces that it has in common with an array either that are not implemented by a dictionary or hash table.